# Android - Compare two list for equality irrespective of the order of items

Tags: android, list

I need to compare two list of objects irrespective of the order

Example:

```
List1 = { object1, object2, object3, object4 }
List2 = { object4, object1, object2, object3 }
```

compare(List1, List2) should return true.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple example for compare two lists in Java,

http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/how-to-compare-two-arraylist-in-java/

[How to compare two different list object in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282883/how-to-compare-two-different-list-object-in-java)

Comment: This is not the answer I am looking for, it mentions to search a common field. In i position when I compare object1 with object4 its going to return false. I need more like, List A i position Object1 is available in list B